# Trigger Space button using Keypress on Javascript

Tags: javascript, keypress

I created a script for the registration form. In the username field, do not allow uppercase & spaces.

When I run the code below, there are 2 alerts ("Space case true" & "upper case true" ) when I press space on the keyboard. It should display only the alert "Space case true" if I press the space key. And "upper case true" if entered in an uppercase field. All errors in the column will be cleared.
is there something wrong with my code?

```js
document.getElementById("usr").addEventListener("keypress", keyPress);

function keyPress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    alert('Space case true');
    return document.getElementById("usr").value = "";
  }
}

function inputUsername(e) {
  var character = document.getElementById("usr").value;
  if (character === "") {
    document.getElementById("usr").value;
  } else if (character === character.toUpperCase() || character !== character.toLowerCase()) {
    alert('upper case true');
    document.getElementById("usr").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="..." method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" value="John">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="Doe">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $last_name_err; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="jdoe@doe.com">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="usr" name="username" class="form-control" value="" oninput="inputUsername()">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Clear">
  </div>
  <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
</form>
```

Comment: What code trigger `inputUsername`?

Comment: When `character` in `inputUsername` is just whitespace, then your `character === character.toUpperCase() === true` and does not evaluate second expression (expression optimisation). Change it to `&&`

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: This statement does nothing at all `if (character === "") {
    document.getElementById("usr").value;
  } `

Comment: @Justinas But when I fill in a word like "javaS". There is no "upper case true" alert. That's why I use `||` so that if there is a suppressed uppercase letter in the middle of a word, an alert will appear.
Or maybe you can share your code. I'm afraid I misunderstood.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm sorry, it's my fault. I'm a new member. Thank you for helping me, I will read it.

Comment: @mplungjan If I don't use the statement. When I want to erase everything manually via the keyboard backspace, the alert "upper case true" appears on the last letter when I delete it.